# Determination of Warping Function for Thin-walled Multi-cellular Beams

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I am trying to find warping function $\mathcal{T}$ for a thin-walled multi-cellular beam. There are four rectangular cells. The governing differential equation for $\mathcal{T}$ is Eq. 8.98 as shown in attached figure. But I don't know the boundary condition.
[image]

Comment: In practice, the fact that you don't know the boundary condition makes these warping function corrections fairly useless, because it is a situation where St Venant's Principle does *not* apply. IMO, if you need to include this level of detail in a structural analysis, you shouldn't be using beam elements anyway.

Comment: … and this is a good example of the engineering principle "design structures that you can analyse easily" If a design only functions correctly because of the exact amount multi-cell beam warping, there is something seriously wrong at the conceptual level, IMO.